# Unhandled Exception or local variable not used

Tags: android, json

I am trying to  encode my data to JSON and send it to a php file (which then sends to a remote database). When insertmatch is called I want the values to be first put into an SQLite table using contentvalues, and then the same values changed to JSON  to be sent. However I keep running into unhandled exception errors, and when I use a try catch or handle the exception, it then says the value of the local variable response is not used.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
public long insertMatch(Match match) {
    //returns the id of the inserted row; if an error occurs it returns -1 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TEAM1, match.getTeam1());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TEAM2, match.getTeam2());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SCORE_TEAM1, match.getScoreTeam1());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SCORE_TEAM2, match.getScoreTeam2());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_START_TIME_STAMP, match.getStartTime());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_END_TIME_STAMP, match.getEndTime());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_LOCATION, match.getLocation());
    Log.d(TAG,"insertMatch: " + values);          

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myhost/data.php");

    try {
        String team_1 = match.getTeam1();
        String team_2 = match.getTeam2();
        int  score_team_1= match.getScoreTeam1();
        int score_team_2 = match.getScoreTeam2(); 
        long start_time = match.getStartTime();
        long end_time = match.getEndTime();

        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on " + team_1);
        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on " + team_2);
        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on " + score_team_1);
        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on" + score_team_2);
        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on " + start_time);
        Log.d(TAG,"Checking if values ok for jsoning on " + end_time);

        String jString = "{\"Necessary??Perhaps, perhaps not. Only time will tell\": { \"team_1\": \""+team_1 + "\",\"team_2\":\""+team_2+"\",\"score_team_1\":\""+score_team_1+"\",\"score_team_2\":\""+score_team_2+"\",\"start_time\":\""+start_time+"\",\"end_time\":\""+end_time+"\"}}";

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", jString));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));                 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 not supported");
    }
    HttpResponse response;//error either here
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //or here
    return db.insert(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null,values);
}
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask a question correctly. It more or less also says to include the complete information, which includes exceptions and error messages etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should copy/paste the whole error, since you are not giving much information.

Anyways, it is weird an exception that informs of a local variable not used, since thats more likely a waarning, but anyways, if you dont use the variable response, you dont have to declare it. so your lines

```
 HttpResponse response; 
 response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

should be just

```
 httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Anyways i think the error is somewere else, probably en how you build the httpost variable. The full information from the logcat will help.